# How much damage will occur to a tyre which is flat for a week?

Tags: tires, fix-a-flat

On Monday, when I took my car out, it felt normal, but after about 300 meters on a busy road, another driver said my rear tyre was flat. I returned home and parked my car on the road in front of my garage.

Yes, the tyre was flat. I left it there, thinking I will change the tyre at night. I later realized that the spare tyre was itself flat, and I had forgotten to fix that.

Now, I will be able to fix the spare tyre and replace the rear tyre only by the weekend.

Will the tyre get damaged in this stationary condition on the road ? Will it be safer if I drive it into my garage ?

Or should I drive it about 3 km to the nearest repair shop ?

Comment: Driving with flat tire can damage it or slice it. The tire will be fine for a week if isn't too hot outside to make tire deform.

Comment: @AsenM , It is luckily not too hot, I will not be driving it, "tire will be fine for a week" : thanks, I am less worried now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driving 300 M on a flat tire is easily enough to ruin the tire. The damage can be in the tire and not be visible .If it is low but not flat ,it may still be alright. Stationary on a flat/low tire should not damage it . Think in terms of how you can take the spare and/or the flat tire to the service shop without driving on them. Or , there are inexpensive air pumps the run on the car battery that will put in enough air to drive it to service. Rarely is a leak so bad that a small pump is unable to temporarily inflate it.

Comment: +1 , "Stationary on a flat tire should not damage it" , thanks , I am less worried now ! Nice to know about "inexpensive air pumps the run on the car battery" , I will explore that.